# Headers in PHPmailer

Tags: phpmailer, php

I am using phpmailer for sending messages. Iam receiving following in header of the messages ..

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server.mywebsiteee.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mywebsiteee.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server.mywebsiteee.com: acl_c_authenticated_local_user: harvest
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir:
```

My question is how can i remove this X-antiabuse, X-get, x-source from the header of the message.
If we changed these headers can we add alternate headers in our company name for example X-Mycompany-notify, X-Mycompany-priority etc likewise,

Your advices beyond my questions are also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is probably the MTA that is adding the additional headers before it sends on your message, so that would not be controllable when creating the message via PHPMailer

Comment: It isn't possible to remove these headers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472847/remove-unwanted-headers-from-email-for-security-risks

Comment: @AbhishekSJain Tks, in my point of view it is possible to do that, I had seen that type of headers in different emails i received :)